# Oracle query data with same id column name on different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to run my `Oracle` data query with below code:

```
SELECT
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK AS S_ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK AS B_ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
FROM
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S,
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B
WHERE
    S.S_ARTICLEID_FK = B.B_ARTICLEID_FK
```

And now getting error below:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "S"."S_ARTICLEID_FK": invalid identifier in...
```

I suspect maybe from this side: `S.ARTICLEID_FK` and `B.ARTICLEID_FK`

but I don't know how to solve the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK AS S_ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK AS B_ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
FROM
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S,
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B
WHERE
    S.ARTICLEID_FK = B.ARTICLEID_FK
```

Comment: Try distinct or use composite key combination to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I can understand an answer that has commas in the `FROM` clause.  I can't understand the upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE S.ARTICLEID_FK = B.ARTICLEID_FK
```

It seems you are trying to use the new fields `S.S_ARTICLEID_FK = B.B_ARTICLEID_FK` as ID for the join and that is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Then, you cannot use a column alias in either the `ON` or the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN
     WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B
     ON S.ARTICLEID_FK = B.ARTICLEID_FK;
```

Comment: Hi I tried but got duplicate data, my query: `SELECT
S.FORM_NO,
S.ARTICLEID_FK AS S_ARTICLEID_FK,
S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
S.ADDEDBY,
B.ARTICLEID_FK AS B_ARTICLEID_FK,
B.DATE_CODE
FROM WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN
WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B
ON S.ARTICLEID_FK = B.ARTICLEID_FK`

Comment: @HiDayurieDave That would be a separate question